# CollectionViewSource can't be DataBound in XAML but can in CodeBehind?

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I hope this makes sense.

I have a Windows Phone 7 app that is using the Windows Phone Databound Application template.

I need to sort my ListBox that is bound to a ViewModel, so I created a CollectionViewSource in XAML and set the ListBox ItemSource to the CollectionViewSource. In the Designer everything works great, and I can see the SampleData just great. However, when I run the app, an exception is thrown:

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message=AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE [Line: 33 Position: 31]
  LineNumber=33
  LinePosition=31

the XAML in question is this:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Items}" x:Key="ItemsSort" >
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <compMod:SortDescription PropertyName="Order" Direction="Ascending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

the ListBox:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsSort}}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
```

Now, if I remove the Source="{Binding Items}" from the CollectionViewSource and instead set it via code:

```
CollectionViewSource itemsView = this.Resources["ItemsSort"] as CollectionViewSource;
itemsView.Source = App.ViewModel.Items;
```

Everything works at runtime, but of course, the Sample Data I have doesn't appear at design time.

I can't really understand why this situation exists, and I would like to have the flexibility of viewing sample data at design time and using XAML to configure the data bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the best thing to do was simply to sort the ItemCollection in code behind and not even bother with CollectionViewSource.

I found a reorder listbox class which also takes care of this automatically.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/01/03/wp7-reorderlistbox-improvements-rearrange-animations-and-more.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have always made my CollectionViewSource a property of the view-model. I never tried it with the static resource like you are doing, but the below hint might help you anyway.

The ListBox ItemsSource binding should be set to CollectionViewSource.View, not the CollectionViewSource.

Try this in your view-model:

```
ItemsSort = new CollectionViewSource();
ItemsSort.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Order", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
ItemsSort.Source = Items;
```

Try this in your XAML (notice the .View in the binding path):

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path={ItemsSort.View}}">
```

Edit: the above hint was for full Silverlight -- hopefully that works for Windows Phone too but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score -1):

How many other clients of the "ItemsSort" resource are there in the page.  It placing binding on something in a resource dictionary always looks a little ropey to me.

Try this:-

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Items}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <compMod:SortDescription PropertyName="Order" Direction="Ascending"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource> 
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and the IDE told me that a CollectionViewSource is not valid in an ListBox.ItemsSource

Answer (score -1):

Just for clear: Windows Phone doesn't support `CollectionViewSource`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.sortdescriptions(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Platforms
Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported)
```

Comment: who said so? I've been using it my whole life. check this link http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CollectionViewSourceIsCrazyUsefulForBindingToFilteredObservableCollectionsOnWindowsPhone8.aspx